# How to split and merge cells in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab

- In [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), given the following code cell, how may it be split into multiple cells?

[image]

- Likewise, given the following cells, how may they be combined into a single cell?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When working directly with JupyterLab, not in an IDE.

[image]

- [JupyterLab: splitCell](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/functions/notebook.NotebookActions.splitCell.html)

  - [Source](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/main/packages/notebook/src/actions.tsx#L155)
- In order to split one cell into many cells:

  - Place cursors where the split is desired, and then press and release <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
  - Multiple cursors may be placed, by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and clicking the location for the cursor.

[image]

- [JupyterLab: mergeCells](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/functions/notebook.NotebookActions.mergeCells.html)

  - [Source](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/main/packages/notebook/src/actions.tsx#L252)
- In order to merge multiple cells, into one cell:

  - Select the desired, consecutive cells, by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, and clicking in the margin, where the `[ ]` is, which will highlight the selected cells.
  - While still holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, press <kbd>m</kbd>, and then release both keys.

[image]

- The resulting merged cell, will have a space between the code from each cell, as does the first image in this answer.

  - This is the expected behavior [`newModel.value.text = toMerge.join('\n\n');`](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook/src/actions.tsx#L226)

---

#### Resources

- [JupyterLab Read The Docs](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html)
- [All NotebookActions](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/modules/notebook.NotebookActions.html)

Answer (score 7):

For those that come here for [Jupyter in VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter), you can merge cells by:

1. Selecting the cells (using shift + arrow is supported)
2. Right click > Join With Previous Cell (or Join With Next Cell)

Join With Previous Cell key: `Shift+Alt+Windows+J`

Join With Next Cell key: `Alt+Windows+J`

---

**NOTE**: that it will join the selected range + previous or next cell. So, if you just want to merge two cell, no need to select using shift + arrow.

Comment: You can also recreate the default shortcut for jupyter by going to your keyboard shortcuts and setting shift+m for `notebook.cell.joinSelected` (Notebook: Join selected cells). If you open the json file through the command palette, you can set the when trigger to `"when": "notebookEditorFocused"`.